# Where does the exponential time complexity in LDA's posterior of topics arise?

Tags: topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc, time-complexity

In [Finding scientific topics](http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/papers/sciencetopics.pdf) (PNAS 2004) the authors derive the (marginalized) posterior distribution of topic assignments given the observed word and arrive at equation (4). Then, immediately after, they write that this is intractable to compute by brute force since:

> Unfortunately, this distribution cannot be computed directly, because the sum in the denominator does not factorize and involves $T^n$ terms, where $n$ is the total number of word instances in the corpus.

How do you see that the denominator in (4) involves $T^n$ terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posterior equation in the LDA helps you determine the topic association of each word,

$P(\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{w}) = P(\textbf{w}, \textbf{z}) / \sum_{z} P(\textbf{w}, \textbf{z})$

In the model you have $T$ topics, hence each word can be associated with one-of-$T$ topics. Since you have $n$ words in the corpus, the total number of combinations of allocating each word with $T$ topics is,  $T^{n}$.

Hopefully this cartoon makes it clear,

[image]